# gor error message when deleteing comment in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel 6 project and I have following CommentController,

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::find($id);

        $this->validate($request, array('comment' => 'required'));

        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->save();

        Session::flash('success','Comment Created');

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $comment->post->id);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::find($id);
        return view('comments.delete')->withComment($comment);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $comment = Comment::find($id);
        $post_id = $comment->post->id;
        $comment->delete();

        Session::flash('success','Deleted Comment');

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post_id);
    }
```

and My routes are as following

```
Route::delete('comments/{id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@destroy', 'as' => 'comments.destroy']);

Route::get('comments/{id}/delete', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@delete', 'as' => 'comments.delete']);
```

but when I try to delete comment got following validation error message
`The comment field is required.`

how could I fix this problem here?

**edit.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
<div class="col-sm-6">
                <form action="{{ route('comments.destroy',  $comment->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because HTML forms can't send `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` requests, we must "spoof" the request and include an input field that tells Laravel which type it is sending. You can read about that [here.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#method-field)

Technically, this means inserting the following for your delete form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
```

Laravel comes with different helpers that help you achieve this. In your update form, you have already done this by adding the `method_field('PUT');`. Here, you are instructing Laravel that this is a PUT request, and we need to do this too in your delete form.

The `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` simply needs to change to `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` or you can use the built-in `@method('delete')`

Like this

```
@section('content')
<div class="col-sm-6">
                <form action="{{ route('comments.destroy',  $comment->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

You can inspect your form HTML in the browser and notice the hidden input field added automatically.

Comment: it is working fine. could you explain some your answer?

Comment: good understood

Comment: @Okurawa You can read the edit for a more detailed description.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->validate($request, array('comment' => 'required'));
```

In your blade view, if you are not posting a `comment` in your form, you will be facing this error `The comment field is required`

Make sure you are posting a comment, or any typo's.

Posting your blade view would help us alot more.